# Swift - Accessing name from peoplePickerNavigationController

Tags: ios, swift

i'm trying to access datas like name, phone, etc. using peoplePicker, i have the following func:

```
func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController, didSelectPerson person: ABRecordRef) {
    let phone: ABMultiValueRef? = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty)?.takeRetainedValue()
    let name: ABMultiValueRef? = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)?.takeRetainedValue()

    if (ABMultiValueGetCount(name) > 0) {
        let indexName = 0 as CFIndex
        let name = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(name, indexName).takeRetainedValue() as! String

        print("name of selected contact = \(name)")
    } else {
        print("No name")
    }

    if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phone) > 0) {
        let indexPhone = 0 as CFIndex
        let phone = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phone, indexPhone).takeRetainedValue() as! String

        print("phone for selected contact = \(phone)")
    } else {
        print("No phone")
    }
}
```

it works with phone but it gives me an error with contact name `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)`, why?

**EDIT: Screenshot**

[image: screen]

**SOLUTION:**

```
let name = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)?.takeRetainedValue()

    if (name as! String != "") {

        print("name of selected contact = \(name)")
    } else {
        print("No name")
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @RomanSalabay: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

Comment: do you what line the error is laying on?

Comment: @Francesc: if (ABMultiValueGetCount(name) > 0) {

Comment: @Mono.WTF: did you check if `name` is `nil`?

Comment: @appzYourLife: yes i did, it isn't!

Comment: @appzYourLife: please check edit, name is actually "John"

Answer (score 0):

Just an hypothesis.

`ABMultiValueGetCount` does accept a param of type `ABMultiValueRef!` while you are passing it `name` that has this type `ABMultiValueRef?`.

In Swift this is not a problem but these function are bridged to C so let's try to fix this inconsistency.

Please in this line

```
let name: ABMultiValueRef? = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)?.takeRetainedValue()
```

replace the `?` with this `!`, like showed below:

```
let name: ABMultiValueRef! = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)?.takeRetainedValue()
```

And let me know if it does work.